# Is a directory removed when its number of hard links becomes 0?

Tags: directory

Is a directory removed when its number of hard links becomes 0?

A directory always has at least 2 as its number of hard links, because of `.`. When `rm -r` a directory, does it decrease the number of hard link from 2 to 0 by 2 instead of 1?

Can the number of hard links of a directory ever be 1?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly not all filesystems use `.` and `..` as hard links. this is documented in the gnu find manual. I am going to ignore those filesystems for the rest of my answer because they were not designed for unix and only complicate things without adding clarity. I am also going to ignore the root directory and mount points for the same reason.

the number of links to a directory is never less than two because of `.` and `..`. The number of subdirectories is equal to the number of links minus two. Because of this you cannot link or unlink a directory, so `rm -r` will `stat` a file before deleting and use `rmdir` instead of `unlink` on directories. The two system calls use completely different code paths in the kernel.

Comment: Thanks. A directory has a hard link `..`, only when it has a subdirectory, correct? So `..` isn't always present for a directory, right?

Comment: `..` is present in each directory that *is* a subdirectory. which is all but `/` which has one too, so all directories.

Comment: (1)  If a directory has no subdir, the directory doesn't have a hard link `..` to itself.  What are the hard links to the dir? the file with the pathname, and `.`? (2) why do you ignore mount points?

Comment: If the directory is a sub-directory. the entry `..` will point to the parent.  As a special case the root directory link points to itself.  This allows `cd ..\..` and similar commands to work as expected no matter where you are.  You can test with the `stat` command.

Comment: 1. don't confuse is with has, if a directory has  a subdir subdir/.. links to it as does ../dir and `.`. if a directory is a subdir it has a .. which links to it's parent. 2. mountpoints reference  inodes on other filesystems with enough special cases to behave almost identically but there are edge cases and special handling of .. so unless you are specifically working with mounts it is much easier to just pretend they are a regular directory, unless you are doing something interesting like trying to remove one (unmount it first) or trying to deal with files obscured by a mount.

Comment: You're correct that the link count is never less than 2, but it's not because of `..`. It's because of `.` and the name in the parent directory that points to it. The only exception is the root, which has no parent. But it has `..` pointing to itself, so it also has link count = 2.

Comment: In FSes designed for Unix, the root has `..` as well but is itself its father. If a reason to ignore “/” exists, then it’s FAT where the root directory isn’t a file-like object but a designated segment of blocks outside data clusters’ area.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi, I was trying to ignore all the special cases to make things easier to understand while not denying the exist.

Answer (score 11):

Any file on a conventionally designed UNIX filesystem whose **reference count** (e.g. the sum of the hardlink count *and* the number of open file handles*) reaches 0 is removed. However, on modern UNIX systems, the `rmdir` system call removes an empty directory in a single operation rather than removing `.` and `..` one-by-one.

In historical UNIX systems, however, this system call did not exist. Instead, the `rmdir` *command* was a setuid program ([source code can be found here](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/src/cmd/rmdir.c)) which checked that a directory was empty (other than the special entries), and then removed `..` and `.`, in that order, and then removed the directory itself, all with the `unlink` system call which only root was permitted to use on directories (hence why the command was setuid). So, on those systems, the link count of a directory would momentarily be 1 after `.` was removed but before the directory was removed from the parent directory, then it would be 0.

The `rm` command, incidentally, prevented even root from removing directories. And `rm -r` would call out to the `rmdir` command to remove directories after emptying their contents.

On these historical systems, misusing the `unlink` call from a program running as root, running into a race condition with `rmdir` or `mv`, or creating a file in a process whose current directory has been deleted (modern systems prevent this), could result in dangling files or directories which have a hardlink count above 0 but do not exist in the directory tree. This condition was detected by `dcheck`, and is still one of the checks in `fsck` since it remains physically possible on most filesystems.

---

Filesystems are, incidentally, not required to implement directories (including `.` and `..`) as normal files that have hardlinks. On these filesystems, the hardlink count of a directory will always be reported as `0` (but of course, its existence within the parent directory qualifies for a "reference count" of 1).

---

The behavior of of a removed directory (e.g. when examined by a process which has it already open or has it as its current directory) and the exact meaning of the "link count" of a directory are unspecified. On Mac OS X, for example, it **will report a hardlink count of 2**, even though it has no real hardlinks. Even though `.` and `..` do not appear in the listing, the directory can be opened and `stat` may be called with the name `.` or `..`. On Linux, the link count is 0 but `.` and `..` likewise still work.

Mac OS X also reports the number of *all files* in a directory as the link count, instead of just the number of subdirectories. But it is 2 even when `.` and `..` are gone.

---

*This includes normal open descriptors, memory-mapped sections (including e.g. executing binaries and shared libraries), and process current directories.

Comment: `strcpy` to a fixed-size array in a setuid executable... these were good times!

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini There's actually a published exploit for `mkdir` based on the fact that it has to do the same thing in reverse.

Comment: I think I found it: http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1/365038/2004-05-31/2004-06-06/0 :)

Comment: asking about `rmdir`, wouldn't removin `..` remove the parent directory?

Comment: @edwardtorvalds No, I was referring to the removal of the ".." link itself, not the parent directory it points at.